# How etcd cluster handles node failure and how many can fail?

Tags: etcd

I have 7 nodes running etcd cluster.

4 of them fails.

Will etcd stop working when majority of nodes is down?

Comment: Yes, if you have two locations A and B that are relatively close together, you cannot run four masters/instances in one location A and three masters/instances in the other location B. If A goes offline, four masters fail and site B only throws timeouts. :(

Answer (score 2):

If 4 out of 7 nodes in an etcd cluster fail, the cluster will stop working due to majority loss. Please refer to the following explanation about fault tolerance: (source: https://coreos.com/etcd/docs/latest/admin_guide.html)

> Fault Tolerance Table
>
> It is recommended to have an odd number of members in a cluster. Having an odd cluster size doesn't change the number needed for majority, but you gain a higher tolerance for failure by adding the extra member. You can see this in practice when comparing even and odd sized clusters: